# Java atomic file move duplicates files on power loss

Tags: java, linux, debian, filesystems, ext4

Java application does an atomic file move the following way:

```
Path source = Paths.get(fullFileName + ".tmp");
Path target = Paths.get(fullFileName);

Files.delete(target);
Files.move(source, target, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
```

Source file exists or gets created before the move.
Source and target are colocated and have the same `FileSystemProvider` as a result.
With atomic move option I expect only one of the files to be present in the system at any given moment or an exception to be thrown.

Nevertheless, when a power loss occurs I find both source and target files on the drive with the same contents.
I don't exclude other potential problems, but so far it's been reliably leaving duplicates.

```
File system: EXT4
Storage type: eMMC Flash
CPU Architecture: ARM
OS: Debian 4.9.11-02300-ga1ac172-dirty #2 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr 23 12:58:56 CDT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Am I missing something?
Does this mean the atomic move not supported?

Comment: You have the linux tag; how exactly does this relate? Is the operating system relevant here? Is the problem exclusive to linux?

Comment: There's no sign of the problem being OS specific. I just listed everything even remotely relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what an atomic move is:

1. Only the move is atomic. The rest of your file processing is not.
2. POSIX atomicity guarantees are for functioning software, not power loss situation.

Consider your code:

```
void foo(String fullFileName) {
    // 1
    Path source = Paths.get(fullFileName + ".tmp");
    // 2
    Path target = Paths.get(fullFileName);
    // 3
    Files.delete(target);
    // 4
    Files.move(source, target, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
    // 5
}
```

If the program is interrupted at 1, 2 or 3, then you leave both files on the system. Your atomic move has not been invoked yet, so nothing about having a move in there will affect anything.

If the program is interrupted at 4 or 5 you will only have a single file, but if power is interrupted, then there are no longer any guarantees about the state of the filesystem when it comes back up.

It sounds like what you want is a database with support for transactions.

Comment: In reality the source file is created at 3, but I see what you're saying. After the source file creation and before deletion of the target both files exist.